# Unit Testing a Zend Framework 2 Module With Factory

Tags: php, unit-testing, doctrine, zend-framework2, entity

I'm trying to Unit Test a ZF2 Module I've written, specifically, a service object.

But I'm getting stuck on how to get the service manager (which calls my factory object) into the test class properly. My factory object injects my modules entity object, the Doctrine entity manager, and my module's entity repository.

How do I ensure that the the factory is properly called during the Unit Test?

Comment: Did you read the Tutorial at [http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/tutorials/unittesting.html](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/tutorials/unittesting.html)? There is also a section about _Configuring the service manager for the tests_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I do in my bootstrap.php:

```
public static function init()
{
    if (is_readable(__DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php')) {
        $testConfig = include __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php';
    } else {
        $testConfig = include __DIR__ . '/TestConfig.php.dist';
    }

    $zf2ModulePaths = array();
    if (isset($testConfig['module_listener_options']['module_paths'])) {
        $modulePaths = $testConfig['module_listener_options']['module_paths'];
        foreach ($modulePaths as $modulePath) {
            if (($path = static::findParentPath($modulePath)) ) {
                $zf2ModulePaths[] = $path;
            }
        }
    }
    $zf2ModulePaths  = implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $zf2ModulePaths) . PATH_SEPARATOR;
    $zf2ModulePaths .= getenv('ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS') ?: (defined('ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS') ? ZF2_MODULES_TEST_PATHS : '');

    $serviceManager = new ServiceManager(new ServiceManagerConfig());
    $serviceManager->setService(
        'ApplicationConfig',
        $testConfig
    );
    $serviceManager->get('ModuleManager')->loadModules();
    $serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);
    static::$serviceManager = $serviceManager;
}

public static function getServiceManager()
{
    return static::$serviceManager;
}
```

And in your test class you can jus call Bootstrap::getServiceManager().